# How can i use jQuery datepicker in dynamically

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to show dynamic date picker ,my code is below

```
$(function() {
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    showAnim: "clip",
    gotoCurrent: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});
$('#mdcn_name').click(function(){

            $('<tr class="field" id="row"><td><input type="text" id="expire_date" name="expire_date" class="datepicker" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"/></td></tr>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#dataTabl');


});


});

<table id="dataTabl">
        <tr>
            <th>Exp Date</th>

            </tr>
</table>
```

When i click add row then i need to create/show datepicker dynamically.
Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your datepicker is not initailize for the dynamically appended div.

create a datepicker function

```
function displayDatepicker(){
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
   showAnim: "clip",
   gotoCurrent: true,
   dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
 });
}

$(function() {
     displayDatepicker()  //initialize date picker whn doucment is ready

     $('#mdcn_name').click(function(){

        $('<tr class="field" id="row"><td><input type="text" id="expire_date" name="expire_date" class="datepicker" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"/></td></tr>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#dataTabl');

         displayDatepicker() //call it after the element is appended...now this finds the appended div with a class datepicker and initailze the datepicker...

      });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will not forget your benevolent.

Answer (score 1):

All of the solutions provided will reinitialize all the datepickers, but you really only want to target the new one. Follwing will only target the new datepicker field

```
/* store datepicker options in object*/
var datePickerOpts = {
    showAnim: "clip",
    gotoCurrent: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
}
$(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker(datePickerOpts);
    $('#mdcn_name').click(function() {

        var $row = $('<tr class="field" id="row"><td><input type="text" id="expire_date" name="expire_date" class="datepicker" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"/></td></tr>')
        $('#dataTabl').append($row);
        /* look for datepicker in new row and initialize*/
        $row.fadeIn('slow').find('.datepicker').datepicker(datePickerOpts);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it maybe because the datepicker initialization occurs only once, and most likely before the click event is fired and the input class="datepicker" exists in the DOM?

Move your anonymous function into the .click() function right after the append.

```
$('#mdcn_name').click(function(){
    $('<tr class="field" id="row"><td><input type="text" id="expire_date" name="expire_date" class="datepicker" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"/></td></tr>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#dataTabl');
    $(".datapicker").datepicker({
    ....
    ...
    ...
    etc....
```

});

Answer (score -1):

Try placing your function in the

`$(document).ready(function(){})`

This will handle your dom ready events

Refer this link for detailed explanation

http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-domready

Hope this helps